# Must a $\Bbb P$-trivial random element be a.s. constant?

Tags: probability-theory, almost-everywhere

In Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability*, he defines a $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$ is $\Bbb P$-trivial if $\Bbb PA = 0$ or $1$ for every $A \in \mathscr{F}$. We say a random element $\xi$ taking value in a measurable space $(S,\mathcal{S})$ is a.s. degenerate or a.s. constant if there exists $s \in S$ such that $\Bbb P \{\xi = s\} = 1$. Kallenberg proves the following:

> **Lemma:** Let $\mathscr{F}$ be $\Bbb P$-trivial and $\xi : \Omega \to S$ be $\mathscr{F}$-measurable. Then if $S$ is a seperable metric space with $\mathcal{S}$ the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-field, $\xi$ is a.s. constant.

Does this Lemma hold if $S$ is **not** assumed to take values in a separable metric space? Assuming the Lemma fails without this hypothesis, what is a counterexample.

Comment: The problem here is $\{\xi=s\}$ might not be measurable if $S$ is not a seperable metric space. Consequently it doesn't make sense to say $\xi$ being a.s. constant.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Say I also add the condition that $\{\xi = s\}$ is measurable for all $s\in S$?

Comment: Just a thought: if we can construct a Borel probability measure $\mathcal P$ on, say, $l^{\infty}$ such that $\mathcal P \{x\}=0$ for each singleton $\{x\}$ and  $\mathcal P(A)=0 \text {or} 1$ for each Borel set $A$ then the  identity map $\xi$ would give a counter-example.